# React-Router v4 Nested Route Not Matching

Tags: react-router-v4

I am new to React Router and struggling to understand why my implementation is not working. In DevTools, it appears the nested route is created, but when I click on the link that should load it, the whole page instead re-renders as blank. I'm guessing that the link's URL isn't matching the route's path (though as you can see from the screenshot, they are the same) or perhaps that the route is never actually registered and tested for a match?

[Screenshot of React output in Chrome Dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6I2B.jpg)

I put a breakpoint inside the render of the ReportContainer component, but it never got to it.

**App**

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import styles from './App.css'
import { logout } from '../actions/user'
import { userIsAuthenticatedRedir, userIsNotAuthenticatedRedir } from '../auth'

import ProtectedComponent from './App.jsx'
import LoginComponent from './Login.jsx'
import Home from './Home'

const Login = userIsNotAuthenticatedRedir(LoginComponent)
const Protected = userIsAuthenticatedRedir(ProtectedComponent)


function App({ user, logout }) {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className={styles.wrapper}>
        <div className={styles.content}>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
          <Route exact path="/app" component={Protected}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  user: state.user
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { logout })(App)
```

**App.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import mainLayout from '../layouts/main';
import Report from './Report.jsx';

const routes = [
  {
    label: 'Reports',
    subs: {
      links: [
        {
          label: 'Report 1',
          link: '/app/reports/report1',
        }
      ],
      paths: [
        {
          path: '/app/reports/report1',
          component: Report
        }
      ]
    }
  }
];

export class AppContainer extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
        React.createElement(mainLayout, { routes })
    );
  }
}
export default connect(null, null)(AppContainer)
```

**Main Layout**

I hardcoded the Route here instead of building it dynamically from the routes object in case that was part of the problem.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import AppMenuBar from '../components/AppMenuBar';
import Report from '../components/Report.jsx';

const MainForm = ({ routes }) => (
  <div>
      <AppMenuBar screen="app/main" routes={routes} />
      <div style={{ marginLeft: '250px' }}>
        <h1>Main Page</h1>
        <p> Default page for the /app location.</p>

        <Route 
          path='/app/reports/report1'
          key='r1'
          component={Report}
        />
      </div>
  </div>
)

export default MainForm
```

[Screenshot of my rendered App component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPGvR.jpg). This corresponds with the React dev tools output. Clicking on the Report 1 menu item [yields this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ueMp.jpg), aka updated url but screen is blank. A quick look at the React output shows there are no rendered components at all, just the empty routes from App.js.

Should the nested route not work in this scenario and I'm misunderstanding how they are supposed to work? Is BrowserRouter not aware of the nested route and therefore unable to make a match, defaulting to a null component? None of the examples I've found span the nested routes across multiple files (though they obviously use multiple components). Wondering if there is something there I am missing in my implementation.

If there are known good examples of this kind of pattern I should be referencing, I would appreciate a pointer in the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: what happens if you remove `exact`: change `<Route exact path="/app" component={Protected}/>` to `<Route path="/app" component={Protected}/>`

Comment: @azium Thank you. This just exposes my poor understanding of nested routes. I _think_ I understand why your suggestion fixes it, but I'll go reread the documentation again to understand the matching logic. If you want to repost your suggestion as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted. I'm now getting the expected behavior.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remove `exact` from your parent path.

It's easy to see what's happening if you just write everything inline:

```
<Route exact path="/foo" component={props => {
  // this component will only load if the url is *exactly* /foo
  // it doesn't matter if you have nested routes in here or not
  // because they will never be rendered if the url is not exactly /foo

  return <Route path="/foo/bar" component={FooBar} /> // <-- can't possibly work
}} />
```

Compare that to:

```
<Route path="/foo" component={props => {
  // will always render if *containing* /foo (ie. /foo or /foo/bar)

  // now this nested path will at least be rendered when url is /foo/bar
  return <Route path="/foo/bar" component={FooBar} />
}} />
```